# Exit a bash script when one of the subprocesses exits

Tags: bash, background-process, pid

I'm running several background processes in my script

```
run_gui()
{
    exec ... # the real commands here
}
```

The functions `run_ai1(), run_ai2` are analogous.

Then I run the functions and do the needed piping

```
run_gui &
run_ai1 &
run_ai2 &
while true; do
    while true; do
        read -u $ai1_outfd line || echo "Nothing read"
        if [[ $line ]]; then
            : # processing
        fi
    done
    sleep $turndelay
    while true; do
        read -u $ai2_outfd line || echo "nothing read"
        if [[ $line ]]; then
            : # processing
        fi
    done
    sleep $turndelay
done
```

If any of those three processes exits, I want to check their exit codes and terminate the rest of the processes. For example, if `run_ai2` exits with exit code 3, then I want to stop the processes `run_ai1` and `run_gui` and exit the main script with exit code 1. The correct exitcodes for the different backgrounds processes may differ.

The problem is: how can I detect it? There's the command `wait` but I don't know in advance which script will finish first. I could run `wait` as a background process - but it's becoming even more clumsy.

Can you help me please?

Comment: trap SIGCHLD, it allows execute some statement at child end

Comment: Can you use [Expect](http://expect.sourceforge.net/)? Trapping exiting subprocesses is more elegant in Expect than POSIX shells or Bash.

Comment: @nwk I'm expected to write a bash script. So I doubt this will be allowed.

Comment: @pasabaporaqui whatever I try with trapping `SIGCHLD` comes far from what I described in here. Either the process doesn't exit at all (and doesn't react to SIGINT) or exits prematurely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following script monitors test child processes (in the example, sleep+false and sleep+true) and reports their PID and exit code:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -m

trap myhandler CHLD

myhandler() {
  echo sigchld received
  cat /tmp/foo
}

( sleep 5; false; echo "exit p1=$?" ) > /tmp/foo &
p1=$!
echo "p1=$p1"

( sleep 3; true; echo "exit p2=$?" ) > /tmp/foo &
p2=$!
echo "p2=$p2"

pstree -p $$
wait
```

The result is:

```
p1=3197
p2=3198
prueba(3196)─┬─prueba(3197)───sleep(3199)
             ├─prueba(3198)───sleep(3201)
             └─pstree(3200)
sigchld received
sigchld received
exit p2=0
sigchld received
exit p1=1
```

It could be interesting to use `SIGUSR1` instead of `SIGCHLD`; see here for an example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12751700/4886927.

Also, inside the trap handler, it is posible to verify which child is still alive. Something like:

```
myhandler() {
  if kill -0 $p1; then
    echo "child1 is alive"
  fi 
  if kill -0 $p2; then
    echo "child2 is alive"
  fi 
}
```

or kill both childs when one of them dies:

```
myhandler() {
  if kill -0 $p1 && kill -0 $p2; then
     echo "all childs alive"
  else
    kill -9 $p1 $p2
  fi
}
```

Comment: This will wait for both processes to exit. If the second one were `( yes; echo "exit p2=$?" ) > /tmp/foo &`, then our script won't stop after the `false` command has stopped.

Comment: @marmistrz: Of course, now is your time to add the "kill" commands or whatever you need to stop the other childs.

Comment: Ok, I shouldn't have focused on the `wait`. Why are there more `SIGCHLD`s than the backgrounded processes? And why is sigchld received before the command ends?

Comment: @marmistrz: This is the problem with sigchld, any command used by the script triggers one. For this reason, the suggestion to use sigusr1. I've will edit the answer for an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

A simple idea is to kill the parent process:

```
( sleep 2; echo hola; kill $$) &
```

Beware that if the `set -e` option is enabled, and the first command fails, the `kill` will not be executed. In this case, either disable it via `set +e` or  ensure the commands before `kill` always succeed, e.g. append  `|| true`.